# Paraview programmatically go to a given time step

Tags: paraview

I have a series of frames (time steps) in my data.
In the GUI, I can type in the small box at the top row the time step I am interested in, hit `enter`, and there I am.

**How can I programmatically show a given time step?**

I couldn't find a way to do this, since:

1. With *Start Trace*, action above produces nothing.
2. For an `animationScene` (e.g., `animationScene1 = GetAnimationScene()`)
   I only found the commands
   `animationScene1.GoToFirst()`,
   `animationScene1.GoToLast()`,
   `animationScene1.GoToPrevious()`,
   `animationScene1.GoToNext()`,
   but no way of setting a specific frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not display a specific frame as per its index `istep`, but I could display a specific frame using its real time `tstep`, with

```
animationScene1.AnimationTime = tstep
```

and from a few tests, it seems to work robustly.

To obtain a list of time steps, `animationScene1.TimeKeeper.TimestepValues` seems to do the trick in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
animationScene.AnimationTime = time
```

where `time` is your desired time step. Note that this is the "real" time, not the frame number.

To get a list of available timesteps, use

```
animationScene.TimeKeeper.TimestepValues
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'vtkPVAnimationPython.vtkSMAnimationSceneProxy' object has no attribute 'SetSceneTime'`

Comment: Oops, I listed the underlying C++ member function initially. The property has been corrected.

Comment: That's what I guessed from https://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/cxx-doc/classvtkSMAnimationScene.html#a46ec5983c426f4264ef2ec554b068dec . Do you know hot to get the list of time steps?

Comment: In most cases, `animationScene1.TimeKeeper.TimestepValues` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down. I edited my answer to include it.